# Magento2 Move billing address below shipping address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

I have Magento 2.3 and in My custom OnePageCheckout I moved Billing Address to Shipping Address. I changed LayoutProcessor.php:

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
            ['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
            ['billing-address-form-shared'] = $component;
```

added:

```
unset(
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
            ['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
            ['billing-address-form-shared']
            );

$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']
            ['billing-address-form-shared'] = $component;
        }
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['billing-address-form-shared'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['billing-address-form-shared']['sortOrder'] = 100;
      }
```

I also changed a few other files and it worked, but if the customer is logged, under the Shipping Address and New Address button it is not showing "My biling and shipping address are the same". It is showing up in popup under Shipping Address. How can I move it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the position of a component, you can look for `displayArea`.

Some cannot be done easily, but it worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following link: https://www.tigren.com/billing-under-shipping-address-m2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below extension given here in my blog:

https://marketplace.magento.com/ananta-module-improvedcheckout.html

Tested and worked with 2.4.5

[image]
[image]